# How to use 'scp' to directly send my file to the target location via a gateway?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, gateway

In my Linux computer, usually I login into the target location by SSH:

First, SSH to gateway **rose@xx.xx.xx.xx**,

then, SSH to the target location **fun@yy.yy.yy.yy**

However, I cannot directly transmit file /Users/david/files/A in my computer to **fun@yy.yy.yy.yy** without logining **rose@xx.xx.xx.xx** by 
    '**scp /Users/david/files/A fun@yy.yy.yy.yy**'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a tunnel first: `ssh -L 2222:yy.yy.yy.yy:22 rose@xx.xx.xx.xx`, then you can scp with `scp -P 2222 A fun@localhost`.

Comment: Many thanks. But it seems that  after ** ssh -L 2222:yy.yy.yy.yy:22 rose@xx.xx.xx.xx**, I will login in rose@xx.xx.xx.xx, and then cannot send file A from my computer, since file A is in my computer instead of rose@xx.xx.xx.xx.

Comment: i mean use 2 terminals at parallel.

Comment: Ipor Sircer Stupid me...how to run 2 terminals 'at parallel'? because I still failed.

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: then click `File` on the topleft corner and click on `new terminal` or `new window` (bash is not a terminal emulator. Terminal.app is the emulator)